# Multiple inputs and lines loop to write to file - python

Tags: python-3.x

Currently I'm pasting multiple lines of names which loops through each line and writes into a file. This prompts me to paste values in which works.

However I would like to have another prompt for other values like IPs etc going through the same loop.

Probably something very simple but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
subnet = input(('Paste the subnet mask: '))

quit = '' 

for line in iter(input, quit):

   with open('my_file.yml', 'a') as data_file:
     data_file.write(" - host: " + line + "\n   ip: " + ips + "\n   subnet: 
       " + subnet)
```

Comment: You didn't actually post where you are accepting any input, so I can't see how you are currently getting input.

Comment: @ for line in iter(input, quit): line. Thanks.

Comment: can you post the full code

Comment: I don't think you can do it using iter. You have to go old school and use if else

Comment: Edited the code above. It's just what you see there. Currently it;s just waitng for my input at the "for" line at which point I paste in lines. Only need another prompt to paste IPs too. If there another way I'm happy to try.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there any other way if not using iter?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want without `iter` by using an infinite `while` that only breaks out when no input is entered. I could have also checked for no input with `if not host`, because empty strings return `False` (See: [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)).

The file is only `open`ed once. There no need to repeatedly open it each iteration.

I have used an [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) with the call to `write()`, but you can still use normal strings like you did.

```py
subnet = input('Paste the subnet mask: ')

with open('my_file.yml', 'a') as data_file:
    while True:
        host = input('Enter host: ')
        if host == '':
            break

        ips = input('Enter IPs: ')
        if ips == '':
            break

        data_file.write(f' - host: {host}\n   ip: {ips}\n   subnet: {subnet}\n')
```

Contents of `my_file.yml`:

```
 - host: localhost
   ip: 192.168.0.5
   subnet: 255.255.255.0
 - host: anotherhost
   ip: 192.168.1.1
   subnet: 255.255.255.0
```